# Python openpyxl некорректно записываются данные

Tags: python, json, openpyxl

Всем привет. Занимаюсь парсингом музеев из госкаталога(конкретно json файла). При сохранении описания в xlsx таблицу возникает проблема - у некоторых музеев оно обрывается. В переменную описание записывается целиком, а при записи в xlsx возникает такая проблема. С чем может быть связано?(причем зависит это от кол-ва музеев за раз, если прохожусь по 8 музеям или меньше, все ок. Если больше - то обрывает)

[image: наглядная демонстрация]

код: https://pastebin.com/XK2gavdx
логи с описаниями: https://pastebin.com/PKbY7v4Y

Answer (score 0):

В общем я решил эту проблему. Глюк в самом openpyxl, который мог обрезать часть информации(странно, никогда до этого с таким не сталкивался). Решение - использование xlsxwriter вместо openpyxl. Менее удобный и привычный, но зато информацию записывает как надо